# How to repair invalid extension paths in devenvexe.config

Tags: oracle, visual-studio

After reinstalling Oracle Developer Tools 12.1.0.1 the extension is broken, it cannot load Oracle.VsDevTools.15.0.dll. Fusion log reveals that Visual Studio 2017 is trying to load the dll from this path:

c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\common7\ide\extensions\51aotvmw.pue\

The directory 51aotvmw.pue is empty, but I can see that the dll exists in the directory jqxrgi52.s10 I cannot find any other occurrences of Oracle.VsDevTools.15.0.dll on my PC.

If I just copy the content from 51aotvmw.pue to jqxrgi52.s10, the dll still does not load and the IDE complains about a version mismatch.

I cannot finde any configuration of the path 51aotvmw.pue anywhere else than in devenvexe.cfg. But if I edit or remove the invalid path there, it will be changed back to the original values once I started the IDE.

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.VsDevTools.15.0" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" culture="neutral"/>
  <codeBase version="4.122.1.0" href="c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\common7\ide\extensions\51aotvmw.pue\Assemblies\Oracle.VsDevTools.15.0.dll"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

I attempted several reinstalls of the Oracle Developer Tools and ran out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply get rid of this clunky and legacy Oracle Developer Tools, especially if you only need the Oracle managed Client.

simply reference the `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` nuget package. This will also help a lot in case of consistency hell on build, test and production servers!

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/

Comment: I say this is the answer because I also finally abandoned the Oracle Developer Tools.